# Xcode failed to download. Use the Purchased page to try again

Tags: app-store, xcode9, macos-sierra

[image]I am not able to download the Xcode from new MacBook Air. Here is the configurations

MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4

Xcode version to download - 9.3

Comment: [apple.se] dupe: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/61646/90404

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday, I also got the same error while installing Xcode on my MacBook Pro. I am on macOS High Sierra version 10.13.4. I tried various methods available on various forums and Apple's website but to no avail. I believe most of the proposed solutions are not for High Sierra. I also feared it might be due to some residual file or I messed up somehow since I have already installed/uninstalled Xcode several times.

However, today I got some update for High Sierra and after installing it, I tried installing Xcode again and bingo!! It installed successfully. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with app store. Maybe poor network condition too. 
Try downloading it form this link here https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: It is working now. I did nothing and now it is being downloaded from the App Store by it self.